# SSRS - calculations from different datasets

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am new to SSRS and need help in completing this. 
I have a SSRS report which has 2 different datasets `Dataset 1` & `Dataset 2`. In `Dataset 2` I have to use a calculation in one of the rows, which requires values from `Dataset 2` and `Dataset 1`. Please see the image attached for the layout of the report and for other details. I would request your help in achieving the orange highlighted fields.

[image]

Comment: you cannot refer to two different datasets in SSRS within one table object, you could try to get the calculation from the query behind.

Answer (score 1):

It is generally better to perform these calculations in the query if possible, but it is not impossible to include items from datasets other than the specified dataset for a tablix.

Depending on exactly how your datasets are set up, you may be able to use the [Lookup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/report-builder-functions-lookup-function) function. This assumes you have a one-to-one relationship between the datasets. You can also sort of trick the function into working for datasets that don't have an explicit one-to-one relationship.

It's a little hard to tell your dataset structure from the information provided, I have a feeling your screenshot doesn't accurately depict your structure. Assuming your datasets are structured something more like this:

```
+------------------------------------+
| Category      | Date       | Value |
+------------------------------------+
| Gross Revenue | 2017-08-01 | GR8   |
| Gross Revenue | 2017-09-01 | GR9   |
| Gross Revenue | 2017-10-01 | GR10  |
| Profit        | 2017-08-01 | P8    |
| Profit        | 2017-09-01 | P9    |
| Profit        | 2017-10-01 | P10   |
+------------------------------------+
```

and similar for Dataset 2, you should be able to use something like this to access the value from the other dataset:

`=Lookup(Fields!Date.Value & "Cash Flow Rate", Fields!Date.Value & Fields!Category.Value, Fields!Value.Value, "Dataset2")`

Answer (score 0):

in SSRS each tablix object can only have one dataset. what you want to do is not possible using two different datasets. i'll suggest to do all calculations at query level in your dataset2.